# I want to display the "Attributes" in a specific order in the drop-down in woocommerce products admin section

Tags: woocommerce

I want to display the "Attributes" in a specific order in the drop-down in woocommerce product admin section., The Attributes have not been entered in the correct order. It's now too late to redo it, so I want to list them in the drop-down menu as they are supposed to appear. It's too time consuming for the person entering the data to scroll up and down this list. It would be faster if they were already in the correct order. I have seen how to force them to display in a specific order on the front end but not in the admin section - Thanks

Comment: Go to the attributes tab and drag and drop them into the desired order.

Comment: I don't want to do this -It's too time consuming - The Attributes have been created at different times so now when applying about 20 Attributes to a product we have to go up and down the drop down menu to  add them in the correct order or we add them and we reorder them by dragging them - Both method are very time consuming. If the Attributes were in the correct order in the drop down that would save a lot of time. Thanks

Comment: What's the specific order? I will have to give some thought to how to programatically do this. Ordering them alphabetically seems the most doable.

Comment: The [`woocommerce_get_product_attributes`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/dbd6479f4565add0838423924121938b0033fac5/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1404) is very promising, though it might be best to update the order they are *stored* in so that you only have to do the re-ordering once.

Comment: I agree it would be nice to update the order they are stored.

Comment: To make sure they display in the correct order on the front end I added the code below in "product-attributes.php"  and it seems to be working fine. but it would be nice in in the drop down on the product page it would show the same way. I don't know what file to modify for this.

Comment: FYI The drop down in the product/add attributes shows them in alphabetical order.

Comment: <?php endif; ?>

<?php

$attributes['pa_maker']['position'] = '1';
$attributes['pa_model-name-type']['position'] = '2';
$attributes['pa_man-lady']['position'] = '3';
$attributes['pa_model-case-ref']['position'] = '4';
$attributes['pa_case-serial']['position'] = '5';

Comment: Sorry  couldn't paste the entire code due to the character limits on the comments. But you can get the idea. Thanks

Comment: I'm 90% certain that running a custom `uasort()` on the `_product_attributes` meta for each product is the solution. You can see that is what WooCommerce is doing [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/dca1e4a53adae7a8b6aa67066e76109898ce5c7b/includes/api/v2/class-wc-api-products.php#L940-L951) on save. However, I don't understand `uasort` well enough yet to suggest what the custom compare should be.

Answer (score 4):

Run this code once and then remove it. So load it into a plugin, activate the plugin, then deactivate. I thought about auto-deactivating or creating a run once kind of transient, but I'll let you handle it. Those can actually be a hassle if the code isn't right the first time.

Maybe you could adapt the 2nd function to also run on `save_post` or replace [`attributes_cmp()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/dca1e4a53adae7a8b6aa67066e76109898ce5c7b/includes/api/v2/class-wc-api-products.php#L940-L951) in case shop managers add the attributes in the wrong order in the future. There actually *is* a filter called [`update_post_metadata`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L122) that would allow you to consistently apply this to every time the post is updated and the meta is saved.

**WARNING** backup your database! This code is destructive and will permanently change your DB and has *not* been tested beyond seeing the the new sort function worked on a demo array. Use at your own risk.

```
function so_35733629_update_products(){
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'meta_value'       => '',
        'post_type'        => 'product',
        'post_status'      => 'any',
    );
    $products_array = get_posts( $args );

    foreach( $products_array as $product ){
        $attributes = get_post_meta( $product->ID, '_product_attributes', true );
        if( ! empty( $atttributes ) ){
            $attributes = so_35733629_reorder_attributes( $attributes );
            update_post_meta( $product->ID, '_product_attributes', $attributes );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'so_35733629_update_products' );

function so_35733629_reorder_attributes( $attributes ){

    // here is the desired order
    $order = array( 
        'pa_maker', 
        'pa_model-name', 
        'pa_man-lady', 
        'pa_model-case-ref',
        'pa_case-serial'
    );

    $new_attributes = array();

    // create new array based on order of $order array
    foreach( $order as $key ){
        if( isset( $attributes[$key] ) ){
            // add to new attributes array
            $new_attributes[$key] = $attributes[$key];
            // remove from the attributes array
            unset( $attributes[$key] );
        }
    }

    // merge any leftover $attributes in at the end so we don't accidentally lose anything
    $new_attributes = array_merge( $new_attributes, $attributes );

    // set the new position keys
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $new_attributes as $key => $attribute ){
        // update the position
        $new_attributes[$key]['position'] = $i;
        $i++;
    }

    return $new_attributes;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the only way to go. The `"position" => $i` was the answer we looking for, when creating the attributes manually!

Answer (score 3):

Simply go to

> Products -> Attributes

, Select attribute you want to reorder. Then click 'Configure Terms' icon. Here you will see all the attribute terms. Just drag and drop in the order you want. Hint :

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot  but I am not looking a reordering the "terms" of the attributes which is easy (drag). I want to show the Attributes in a specific order in the drop-down menu on the product page when adding them to a product. The Attributes' terms are not the issue.

Comment: show me the structure you want. because i think no one can tell what you want?

Answer (score -1):

Actually the ordering is based on the descriptor, them being ordered alphabetically.
The name can be whatever, but the list will display alphabetically BY THE DESCRIPTOR.
So a simple solution for a medium sized finished website would be adding a few numbers at the beginning of the descriptor.
EG:

- 1size
- 24weight
- 25material
- 300appearance

[check this image with my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfChR.png)